# All of my h1 tags go the right when zoomed in

Tags: html, css, zooming

I'm new at this and I don't know why the text inside my h1 tag goes to the right when I zoom in.

**Here's the CSS code:**

```
h1 {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    margin-right: 500px;
    margin-left: 500px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Also, I didn't use `<div>` because I didn't know what it was for when I began to code. I tried to change it but everything is build around my current technique.

Thanks.

Comment: `margin-left:500px` and `margin-left:500px` seem the most likely culprit, you should use: `margin:auto` for centering. I think the problem is the page width gets to less than 500px when you zoom in and the margins can't handle it with the `min-width`.

Comment: I use those for styling. It adds a line above and below the text and I don't want those lines to take all the width. And the `min-width` is me trying out a solution, I forgot to remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing as you are just beginning to code - this looks great!

I did the same thing when I first started and I'm pretty sure most people do.  But Like the comments say - {margin: 0 auto} works best.
Divs are very, very important.

Use chrome's development tools - This is a good way to add and remove CSS rules quickly.
View -> Developer -> Developer Tools.
Navigate to the header through the collapsable menus, click it and note the associated rules on the right.  Uncheck Your margin left and right to test the CSS rules.

You need to remove your margin-left: and right 500px;

I would STILL suggest something like this

```
<div id="container">
<h1> Your Header </h1>
</div>
```

This way, you can target JUST the h1 in the div of container in your css

```
#container h1 {
text-align:center
}
 #container{
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

If this worked, please mark answered

Comment: I actually need all the h1 on the website to be the same. I coded it in a sloppy way and making everything work with a `<div>` tag would be a lot of re-writing. Maybe I should show you my [website](http://www.psichologique.net78.net) ?
 (I don't win anything from the ad)

Comment: I checked your site.  Everything stays centered when I zoom in.  What browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome. It does it on my other computer as well (which uses Chrome too). It happens when I zoom above 125%. Which is maybe 150% on a 1080p monitor.

Comment: did you wrap your h1 in a div?

Comment: No but never mind. It worked. I was looking at hosted website, not my testing one. I'm a derp.

Comment: Ok! Haha that happens from time to time!